# Ajax + Codeigniter retornando o "error"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

então eu estou tentando realizar uma requisição em Ajax para salvar um cadastro porém não está dando certo. Estou utilizando o Codeigniter. Toda vez que tento enviar o Formulário o ajax está me retornando o error não sei onde pode estar o erro

```js
$('#enviarAltera').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + '/index.php/contatos/salvarAlterar', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status)
            {
                alert('O aluno foi inserido corretamente!');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar o aluno.');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
    public function alterar($identificador)
    {
        $this->load->model("Contatos_Model");

        $contato = $this->Contatos_Model->buscarId($identificador);
        $pacote = array(
            "contato" => $contato,
            "pagina" => "contatoAlterar.php"
        );

        $this->load->view('index', $pacote);
    }

    //controller
    public function salvarAlterar()
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $this->load->model("Contatos_Model");
        $this->Contatos_Model->salvarAlterar($id, $nome, $telefone, $email);

        redirect("contatos");
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_title">
            <h2>Atualiza Contatos</h2>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="x_content">
            <br>
            <form name='form' id="form" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="POST">
                <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $contato[0]->id; ?>' />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Nome: <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input type='text' id="nome" name='nome' value=<?php echo $contato[0]->nome; ?> id="first-name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 ">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">E-mail: <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input type='text' id="email" name='email' value=<?php echo $contato[0]->email; ?> required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 ">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Telefone:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input data-mask="(00) 00000-0000" id="telefone" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type='text' name='telefone' value="<?php echo $contato[0]->telefone; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                        <input id="enviarAltera" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Alterar" name="enviarform">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Se você ler a documentação do [callback error](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)  verá que esse callback aceita até três parâmetros `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )` provenha esses parâmetros imprima-os e nos mostre o status real do erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a melhor estratégia é separar o backend do frontend a princípio.
Você está tentando tratar o seu backend como uma API Rest porém ele não é (verifiquei que você redireciona para uma listagem após o cadastro). 
Minha sugestão é você tratar a rota '/contatos/salvarAlterar' como um endpoint Rest e trabalhar com HTTP status para retornar sucesso ou erro, utilizando uma aplicação para testar (um Postman por exemplo).
Tem muito conteúdo na web falando sobre Rest, vale a pena dar uma lida em alguns artigos.
Quando seu backend estiver funcionando e retornando os status corretamente, você parte para o frontent. 
Alias, você pode obter os erros através da callback de erro que você definiu, basta colocar o parâmetro da função e utilizá-lo.